What late 50s or early 60s movie had an alien or time traveler showing a group of people a photograph taken of Christ? Similar to 1959 "Cosmic Man."
I've been trying to find a movie I saw on TV  when I was young. In it, a group of early 50s-60s suburbanites are questioning a human-looking man who told them he was an alien, or perhaps a time traveler.
To prove that he was what he said, he showed them a photograph that had been taken of Jesus Christ.
The vintage looked late 50s to early 60s. The film that most closely resembles what I remember is 1959's "The Cosmic Man," but it's not that film. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
